# Converting Date to String and then to Date again in mysql .Combining 2 functions in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

have column which is of type date having default format as YYYY-MM-DD. I want to get date in format DD-MM-YYYY but as date type only. I would like to know how is it possible? I am combining 2 functions together as shown below but i am not getting the desired result

```
STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(emp.doj, '%d-%m-%y'),'%d-%m-%y') as doj
```

Please dont close this questions as its a different one not asked before thanks!!!

Comment: Why are you doing this? What is your overall goal? I ask because it's usually a huge waste of resources to manipulate dates in this way. For example, people do things like this to get rid of the time portion of a date time, when calling `DATE(emp.doj)` would be better

Comment: *having default format as YYYY-MM-DD.* Not default. It is the only representation of DATE datatype value. All another are string-formatted values, values of string type, not date.

Comment: What you're asking makes no sense. The date format is meaningless unless you're displaying it to a user, in which case it matters. If that's what you're doing, leave it as a string. If it's not, you don't need to change the format.

Comment: Much better to store it as its own date format in MySQL. Or store the timestamp then retrieve it and create date object using the timestamp

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. And the table definition. All as formatted text, no images. [mcve]

Comment: i am mapping the column which is of date type to java field also date type but i want to show user result in format DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: The user sees a string. You don't convert it back to a date. The format of the date is for **display** - the database uses `YYYY-MM-DD`. There is absolutely no purpose in converting it to a string in a specific format and then converting it back, because it's going to **convert back to the database's format**.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code - in the client's locale

Answer (score 1):

```
 DATE_FORMAT(emp.doj,'%d-%m-%Y') as doj
```

You have not need to use STR_TO_DATE. use only DATE_FORMAT. It should be work.

Comment: I know but DATE_FORMAT return type is string i need to map the column to field of date type in java i dont want to use any simpledateformat at java side

Comment: But STR_TO_DATE return you ('%Y-%m-%d) this format only, If you need different format, must need DATE_FORMAT. You should use java type casting string to date after retrieve data from database.

Comment: @unknown: You don't seem to be listening. If you convert a string to a date in the database, it's going to convert to whatever format the database is using. What you're trying to do is not only not needed, but it will never work the way you expect. If I have a US one dollar bill, and I get it converted into coins and then back to a US one dollar bill, I don't get a bill that has a Euro symbol on instead - I get a US one dollar bill.  If you convert a SQL date to a string in some format and then convert it back to a SQL date, you're going to get the original SQL date fomrat again.

Comment: @KenWhite Yeah I got it it will converted into the same format i thought i could convert it into a different format.Thanks!!!